# Why does not “npm install” rewrite package-lock.json? And also not generate new one if not exist?

Tags: node.js, npm, package-lock.json

I'm expecting to see changes in my package-lock.json file after adding new dependency in package.json and running npm install - but package-lock.json is not changing. 
Settings:
node version 6.11.0
npm version 3.10.10
I have tried to delete old package-lock.json, after run npm install - no new file was generated.
Can anyone please tell me how to renew package-lock.json? 
**EDIT:** Occasionally me and my coworker have different npm versions, so I have package-lock.json in codebase, but not able to renew it because my current npm version is not supporting this feature. After update all is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`package-lock.json` was introduced in npm v5.
Your version of npm v3.10.10 doesn't use it, you may want to update it

Answer (score 1):

> Why does not “npm install” rewrite package-lock.json?

Because the point of `package-lock.json` is to tell `npm` exactly which modules to install, if present. If not present, npm writes it to "cache" the dependency tree for subsequent installs.

Just `rm package-lock.json` and install again to update `package-lock.json`

> And also not generate new one if not exist?

If you are not getting any `package-lock.json` generated, you most likely have an old version of `npm` that doesn't support it, *or* you have configured `npm` to not generate it (which is possible).

Comment: Removing of old lock file doesn't help.
Can I ask to clarify how to configure npm to generate such file? "npm set package-lock true" doesn't help.

Comment: Added an answer, as yours doesn't provide a concrete solution + is misleading (its not "most likely" an old version or wrong config, it is an old version).

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally me and my coworker have different npm versions, so I have package-lock.json in codebase, but not able to renew it because my current npm version is not supporting this feature. After update all is working fine.